# Creating a Yes No Dialog box

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

I am creating an addon for Microsoft Dynamics Rms. I created a quick Tender button and this button works fine. I want to add a Yes NO dialog box but I am having some problems.

It works if I dont include the MessageBox

```
public class Addin : Addin_Interface
{
    public bool Process(QSRules.SessionClass mySession)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Tender €10", "Tender Amount", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{F12}{DOWN}10.00{{ENTER}");
            return true;
            // return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a red error line on the Process on this line

```
public bool Process(QSRules.SessionClass mySession)
```

The error says Not all code paths return a value. Below is an image of the error

[image: Visual Studio - not all code paths return a value]

Comment: That's because you only return when the `if` condition is true.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
return false
```

after you if-statement to fix this problem. Your problem is that your code does not return a boolean value if the user presses "no" on the message box. But you declared a return type "bool" to your method so the method has to return a bool in every possible code path.

So your code should look like this:

```
public class Addin : Addin_Interface
{
    public bool Process(QSRules.SessionClass mySession)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Tender €10", "Tender Amount", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{F12}{DOWN}10.00{{ENTER}");
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes that got rid of the error in Visual Studio and I could compile the dll. It does not work with Dynamics Rms though. I get the Yes NO dialog box but when I press Yes I get. Attempt to process COM object RMSAddintesttender failed. An unknown error ocurred. As I said in earlier post this works fine without the Dialog Box Yes No

Answer (score 0):

A method that has a return type that is not void must return a value in all possible conditions. Your method only returns a value when the user clicks yes. If the user clicks no then the inner part of the if does not execute which is where your return is.

Here is how I would write it... (there are plenty of ways you could write this)

```
public bool Process(QSRules.SessionClass mySession)
{
    var response = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Tender €10", 
        "Tender Amount", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes;
    if (response)
        SendKeys.Send("{F12}{DOWN}10.00{{ENTER}");
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is dialog Yes No in Visual Studio Form C++;

        System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult ResultDialog = MessageBox::Show("Msg title", "Hello", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Question);

        if (ResultDialog == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes)
        {

            this->Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //some code 
        }
```